# How to pass properties into a require module?

Tags: node.js

In my *index.js* I require a *config* file for connection strings etc, like this:

```
var config = require('./config');
```

*config.js* then does:

```
module.exports = config;
```

so in *index.js* I can use the properties off config like `config.db_connect_string`.

When I also require for instance *db.js* to do the database stuff, how can I access properties of `config` within the functions I create in *db.config* and export back to *index.js*?

Hope this makes sense! I'm starting out with node.

Comment: In `db.js`, you can also `require('./config')` to get access to the same values.  Don't know what else you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that - just wondered if db.js could inherit the values from index.js

Comment: No - there is no "module inheritance".  The way you get access to data in another module is using `require()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what db.js looks like, but you should be able to inject the config object into the db.js module from your index.js file, and then use curried functions to create the db object you want to export.

Like so:

At index.js

```
var config = require('./config');

var { makeDB } = require('./db');

var db = makeDB(config)
```

At db.js

```
module.exports.makeDB =

    // Pass in the expected config object
    function(config) {

        // If your db module needs parameters
        // you can pass them in here
        return function(){

            // Create db module here.

            // The properties of the config object
            // passed in will be available here.

            // Be sure to return the database object.
            return db;
        }
    }
```